# Click button or hide box in iMacros or Greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey, imacros

So I've had an iMacro for about a year now working fine.

The iMacro has the following line in it:

```
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
```

That's because after the tab 2 closes, a dialog popup box appears and the "OK" button needs to be clicked. However, for some reason since a few days now this stopped working. I think the popup box somehow changed.

Here is how the box looks:

[image]

I need to be able to click this, because otherwise I can't continue doing what I need to do. I'm thinking if iMacros can do it (I tried recording with different recording modes, and nothing records when I click the OK button). I'm using iMacros for Firefox by the way. Or, maybe to do it somehow with Greasemonkey? Or if anyone has any other idea?

The website I'm trying to create an iMacro for is called Likesasap.com, and I'm trying to make a script for their website hits category.

Here is the script that I have that worked up until a month ago:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 20
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var min = 2; var max = 3; var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; randomNumber;")
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var min = 4; var max = 5; var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; randomNumber;")
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var min = 25; var max = 27; var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; randomNumber;")
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.likesasap.com/website.php
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=*
TAB T=2
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR3}}
TAB T=1
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=*
TAB T=2
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR3}}
TAB T=1
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=*
TAB T=2
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR3}}
TAB T=1
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR2}}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide enough information for us to duplicate the problem.

Comment: Hey Brock. Okay, I edited my OP to provide the site I'm trying to create a script for, and which category, as well as included the previous script that used to work. I think that's all the help I can provide. Anything missing?

Comment: That's better.  This is now on my "look at" list.  No promises though.

Comment: Okay Brock. Thanks for your time. By the way, I can pay you $2 if you want to help me out with this. Or I can give you Twitter followers, or Facebook followers, or some other social media service like that. I hope you find some time to help me. Thanks

Comment: My hourly rate is over 100 times that. :)  But I'm not for hire at the moment and that's not how we work around here.  You get any help for free and should report anyone who tries otherwise.  Also, I'm not the only guy that can take a stab at this question.

Comment: Okay. I just don't like people "working for me" for free, or doing stuff for me for free. That's why I offered. Thanks